# How to access class variables when class instances are stored in array

Tags: python, arrays, oop

I started object-oriented programming in python and in my program, I decided to store class instances in array, but I don't know how to access class variables now.

```
class apixel(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.posx = random.randint(0, 300)
        self.posy = random.randint(0, 200)
    def do_i_exist():
        print("Yes i do!")

p = [apixel] * 10

for obj in p:
    obj.do_i_exist() #that works
    print(obj.posx)  #but that does not work
```

Comment: Your code only "works" because you incorrectly omitted the `self` argument to the `do_i_exist` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you need to actually instantiate the objects, otherwise `__init__` is never called.

Try:

```
p = [apixel() for _ in range(10)]
```

Per Craig's comment below, the list comprehension calls the constructor 10 times so you get 10 independent objects.

But, the reason your `apixel` didn't have a `self.posx` is that the constructor was never called by your code. You weren't creating a list of *instances* of your class, but rather a list of *references to the class definition*.

Per DanielPryden's comment on your OP, you should either change the signature of your `do_i_exist` method to accept `self`, or annotate it as `static`:

```
# as an instance method, which requires "self":
do_i_exist(self):
    ...

# as a static class method that is the same for all instances:
@staticmethod
do_i_exist():
   ... method body contains NO references to "self"
```

Comment: This will create 10 copies of one object. The OP probably wants a list comprehension like `p = [apixel() for _ in range(10)]` to get 10 independent objects.